# libhid.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, command-line, c

I am trying to install an old program from [here](http://javier.rodriguez.org.mx/index.php/2006/06/10/griffin-radio-shark-icecast2-on-debian-gnulinux)

I can't seem to get it working it kicks back **"shark: error while loading shared libraries: libhid.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"** .... I have been looking for libhid.so.0 and can't seem to find it anywhere. Is there some way to run this with a different and reverse compatible hid controller? Or has anyone figured out how to get radioshark working on a current Linux OS.

Comment: It seems to be an old library, but you can still get it on the svn. See :http://libhid.alioth.debian.org/. Link to the tarball : http://alioth.debian.org/frs/?group_id=30451

Answer (score 0):

I have this working on Ubuntu 14.04. Previously I had it on ver. 10.04 and just copied the missing `libhid.so.0.0.0` and `libusb-0.1.so.4` to a version 14.04 directory with a sym link in `/usr/lib` pointing to them.

I also copied my shark executable from the old version 10.04 system. I have a shell script to set up radio shark stations and run the `arecord` and `aplay` commands. you need to pass the capture device to the `arecord` command. you can get the hardware device by plugging the radioshark into a USB connector and execute:

```
arecord -l.
```

you'll get something like:

```
List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: radioSHARK [radioSHARK], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

the shell commands I use are:

```
sudo shark -fm 97.7
sudo shark -blue 50
arecord -c 2 -f S16 -r 24000 -D hw:2,0 | aplay
```

I have a java GUI application to run all this and select various 
stations but that's not working on Ububtu 14.04 yet.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Next time, please use your [Shift] key for correct CaPiTaLiSaTiOn!  :-)

Comment: I actually hacked it together using fmtools, VLC, darkice, pulseaudio, and icecast2. It worked out pretty good. fmtools can natively change the radio stations from command line and using a pulse audio loopback to icecast2 and darkice I can then record and play the audio using VLC. Also as a consequence of doing it this way I can broadcast the audio across my network to other PC's, and android devices running VLC or devices that can handle .m3u files....   Thanks though. If you want more info on it let me know.